# Handling Multilingual from configuration

Tags: django, django-forms

Right now the way I'm handling Multilingual (for Templates) is created multiple folders like en,de and kept my HTML files. So based on the Language Option it will go and pick appropriate file and render.

But when ever I add new language I have to create whole bunch of new HTML and put it. Insted is there any way to load all labels, place holders, tool tips from any configuration file?

Example:

The below on is for en (English)

```
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter old password"/>
```

Insted of mentioning "Enter old password" here i would like to load it from some configuration file. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `i18n` module for templates.

```
{% load i18n %}

<input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="{% trans 'Enter old password' %}"/>
```

You can read more about it in [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/translation/#internationalization-in-template-code).